# Unable to uninstall Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, uninstallation

I have tried everything suggested in other posts, but nothing seems to completely uninstall Python.

1. I had installed Python 3, which I uninstalled through Control Panel.
2. I uninstalled Jupyter.
3. I found the conda folder and manually deleted it.
4. I ran a search for any `python.exe` file in my entire computer and the computer came up empty handed.
5. I looked at my system variables, but the only variables I have are for MATLAB and Java. None say Python.

However, if I open up Bash on Windows 10 and type in Python, the command line pops up with the following message.

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I have no idea how I'm still able to Python! Please help me debug this!

Comment: check Environment Variables and look for "path" under system variables

Comment: Type `where python` to find out which program is called when you type `python`. Also check you `PATH` variable.

Comment: I only see "Path." Not any "path" or "PATH" and neither contain Python. hmm, interesting indeed. I suspect it might come built in with the bash shell for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out where the python is being called from. Apparently, if you enable Bash on Windows 10, it comes with Python preinstalled. Hence, you can't find it `Programs`, but it is there in the Bash folder.